# Put two array together

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I try to put two array together, but I will not work.

```
$vars['project_title'] =  $data['post_title'];
```

It works if I only print out the array separately

```
echo $data['post_title'];
```

I have also tried the following but it does not work

```
$mytitle = $data['post_title'];
$vars['project_title'] = $mytitle
```

Have I missed something?
thankful for all your help!

Comment: What is your desired outcome? Please be more specific than 'I want both arrays together' :-)

Comment: _Have I missed something?_ Yes, you have missed posting the original array, result and expected result.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the "=" operator, perhaps if you try to use the "=>" operator you might have more luck. For example,

```
$vars = array(
    "project_title" => $data['post_title'],
    "var_1" => "some data",
    "var_2" => "more data"
);
```

and this will give you an array:

```
Array
(
    [project_title] => 'Whatever post_title was set as',
    [var_1] => 'some data',
    [var_2] => 'more data'
)
```

It was difficult to understand what you were asking, in future please could you include the following:

- The desired outcome, be more explicit than just "put two array together". What's the structure of $data, what's the structure of $vars? What is the desired structure of the array that you are trying to construct?
- What output are you currently getting? error? not what you wanted? post exactly what you are getting in the form of a code snippet. Please don't use images, we're all waaaaay too lazy to type code from image.

Hope this answer helps you to get what you are looking for. Please comment below if it does not.